# Add a meta to custom post type which corresponds to a particular taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, front-end

I'm developing a front-end for a project in which I have a custom post type with a custom taxonomy. I want to add a meta value which corresponds to that taxonomy for that custom post type object.

Here is what I want to achieve:

Vendor - Custom post type
Specific Tags - Custom Tax 
Price Onwards - Custom Field for the Custom Tax for that Object.

For e.g. Store1 - Tax234 - $50 onwards

I know how to achieve this in procedural programming as we have the liberty to add as many tables as we want in mysql. I'm wondering how to achieve this in wordpress. I'm a wordpress noob.

Thanks in advance.

[image: This is what I'm trying]

**EDIT 1**
I want something like this plugin - [Taxonomy Metadata](https://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/). But the meta should be stored at post+taxonomy level and not at only taxonomy level.

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with? Finding out if the post has the tag/term? Are you trying to save tax on the backend when they are part of that term?

Comment: @Gazillion as show in the image attached, I want to save the number value which is Price onwards as a meta information for that term_name (bargain guys) and save it in custom post type

Comment: Can't you just show the input in a meta box when the post has the term? Then once you save you hook into 'save_post', check if the post has the term, then save the value?

Comment: @Gazillion - I'm a noob to WP,so not sure of what your trying to say.